# Password strength (XKCD)

Tags: passwords, theory, password-encryption

I don't know if this question is off topic here on SO, so if it is please comment below and I will delete it right away!

I'm wondering if anyone out there would take the time to "dumb" down and explain this XKCD comic for me? I don't understand the entropy part, and why the password that's easy for us (humans) to remember has higher entropy.

Also, is there a way to explain this misinformation in regards to passwords that we have come to accept as common knowledge?

[image: XKCD comic strip]

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not programming related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a own wiki just dedicated to explain xkcd comics http://www.explainxkcd.com
The explanation for this particular comic can be found here: `http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/936:_Password_Strength`

Answer (score -3):

first off (FYI) computer guesses are based of how common and how long a phrase is, but human memory is based on how complex and long something is.

Basically what this comic is making fun of is that common 'good password criteria' has made passwords more complicated but it has to be short to be remembered. But the 'good password' criteria has made more complicated sequences more common. This means that four common medium length words are less common and longer than normal meaning a better password. Basically what was rare(short complex patterns) is now common making what was common (med-long length phrases) rare.